# Debug option is not enabled in DDMS

Tags: android, ddms

I opened DDMS by opening ADT -> Perspective -> DDMS

In the DDMS I find my device got recognized and online as well.However the Debug, Update Heap, Dump HPROF file, Cause GC, update thread, start method profiling,  Stop process etc everything got disabled.

If I open the DDMS directly from terminal the same problem persists.

```
LONM37XV7XJL:~ arihan.sinha$ ddms
```

Can anyone please let me know how I can enable it

I've already done few times the below commands but no luck

```
 LONM37XV7XJL:~ arihan.sinha$ adb kill-server
 LONM37XV7XJL:~ arihan.sinha$ adb start-server
 * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
 * daemon started successfully *

 LONM37XV7XJL:~ arihan.sinha$ adb devices
 List of devices attached 
 HT344W907473   device
```

Also done the DDMS ->right click -> reset but still no luck

Note:- However in the right pane, Threads, Heap, Allocation Tracker, Network statistics etc everything is in enabled state.

Comment: Just to add that we use titanium to make the build. Like ti build --p android --target device

Comment: Got to know that as titanium build it doesn't support the debug mode in actual device. We have already raised a ticket to the appcerlator. However it works with emulator only.